# Marking up table joins in the Microstrategy project metadata with the architect tool?

Tags: join, metadata, microstrategy

I am evaluating Microstrategy 9.0.1 and attempting to build a prototype metadata layer using its Architect tool.  The tool doesn't seem to have any specific means to mark up joins in the way that the editing tools for SSRS data source views or Business Objects universes do.

- How does this work in Microstrategy - I have never used this before and may be making invalid assumptions based on other systems I have seen.
- If one does do this with MicroStrategy, how is it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joins can be done by dragging an attribute (Note you must create the attribute first) across the tables.  The architect tool may or may not get the actual join columns right, but you can edit them in the properties panel.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the attribute editor, another (less graphical) tool used to create and edit attributes, their forms and relationships in hierarchies.  This gives more fine-grain control over exactly how the attributes are linked to database tables and columns.